# Enum Module with AWS Lambda Python 2.7, Deployed with Travis CI

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, virtualenv, travis-ci

I have an AWS Lambda handler in Python 2.7 that is deployed from Travis CI.  However, when I try running the function I received an error from AWS saying that it cannot import the enum module (enum34).  Is there a simple way to resolve this?  Should Travis CI include the virtual environment that Python is running in?  If not, how do I include that virtualenv?

Additionally, when I deploy from Travis CI, it seems to prepend an "index." onto the handler_name field.  Does anyone know why this happens, or how to disable it?  I can't seem to find an answer.

Comment: Seems that "index" is the default module_name, which I was not providing.  So that question is answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.  I was installing the Python modules into a subdirectory of my project root, rather than in the project root itself.

Essentially was doing this:

`pip install -r requirements.txt ./virtualenv/`

when I should have been doing this:

`pip install -r requirements.txt ./`